# Using an adapter to plug an xbox headset into a PC

Tags: adapter, xbox360, headset

I've recently started PC gaming after a few years using Xbox. I now want to play TF2 with a friend, but since TF2 is quite tactical, we need to communicate. I have a headset for xbox that I no longer use as I've cancelled my xbox live account, and I've heard that I can use my headset with my PC. After much googling, I can't find any definitive instructions on how to do this. I have seen a post that says I can use a 2.5 to 3.5 adapter and plug it into my PC. From this information I have 2 questions:

1. Am I able to do this?
2. Which port on my PC do I plug it in to?

Comment: We need more information about the headset in question.  Some console headsets can be plugged into a PC some cannot it entirely depends on certain factors

Comment: @Ramhound It is an insten model. Here is a picture http://ak1.ostkcdn.com/images/products/5894659/75/366/INSTEN-Headset-with-Mic-for-Microsoft-Xbox-360-P13601049.jpg

Comment: I need a specification datasheet on the headset.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have the box for it and I can't find the specs on google :/

Comment: I can't do research because I don't have a full product name and model number

Comment: @Ramhound I bought it off the internet, and it didn't come with a box. The only information I have is that it has "insten" written on the side. I'll try and find out more for you

Comment: @Ramhound OK, the full product name is "INSTEN - Headset w/ Mic For Microsoft Xbox 360". I am unable to fins a model number, but I think this is the only headset insten have made for xbox